# Optional title for Ctrl+L (hyperlink) shortcut is broken

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown, user-interface, hyperlinks

When using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to create a link, the prompt says:

> **Insert Hyperlink**
>
> http://example.com/ "optional title"

If you actually enter enter something with a title, though, it thinks the `"optional title"` is part of the URL.  You get this in your markdown:

```
[link text][1]


  [1]: http://example.com/ "optional title"
```

Instead of the expected:

```
[optional title][1]


  [1]: http://example.com/
```

Comment: Your expectations are wrong :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[link][1]
  [1]: http://www.example.com "title"
```

[Link](http://www.example.com/) is the text of the link, and optional title works well both on the preview and on the posted answer.

"optional title" is the text that goes on the `title` tag, not inside the `<a href=""></a>`.

Answer (score 1):

I can duplicate this - Firefox, Chrome, and IE on Windows XP.

Edit: As voyager pointed out, we're just not looking at the right thing. It's the title, not the link text. I attempted to change my vote, but alas! It is too late.